# Telerik Scheduler - Highlight the day has appoitment

Tags: telerik-scheduler

How I can highlight the cell in the telerik scheduler where there is an appointment on it.  Eg: If 1/6/2011 has appointment, I wish to highlight those day to the green color.  Any one have idea how to do so?  Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can highlight the days in the popup calendar so that you can easily navigate only to these days that have appointments in them. Please Take a look at [this Knowledge Base article](http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/scheduler/how-to-make-appointments-visible-in-the-popup-callendar-of-radscheduler.aspx) of Telerik for more info.